# Importar arquivos CSV do Drive no Google Collab

Tags: pandas

Boa tarde, estou com dificuldades para realizar a importação dos arquivos em csv para o collab.
Fica aparecendo a mesma mensagem de erro que meus arquivos não podem ser localizados na pasta que eu especifiquei (e eles estão lá)

Consegui importar como teste apenas o: **SGL_ESTADOS**

*Não sei se o tamanho do arquivo influência nesse caso, trabalhando no meu PC, consegui importar tranquilamente todos os datasets no Jupyter.*

---

- Comandos executados

```
import pandas as pd
```

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

```
# Importanto data frame - Colab
DM_ALUNOS = pd.read_csv (r'drive/My Drive/Path/Path/DM_ALUNO.csv',
                 skiprows=sorted(random.sample(range(1,n),n-s)),
                 delimiter='|',
                 encoding='latin1', 
                 )

DM_CURSOS = pd.read_csv(r"drive/My Drive/My Drive/[Path/Path/DM_CURSO.csv",
                 skiprows=sorted(random.sample(range(1,n),n-s)),
                 delimiter='|',
                 encoding='latin1', 
                 )
    
DM_IES = pd.read_csv(r'drive/My Drive/My Drive/Path/Path/DM_IES.csv',
                 delimiter='|',
                 encoding='latin1'
                 )

SGL_ESTADOS = pd.read_csv(r'drive/My Drive/Path/Path/SGL_ESTADOS.csv',
                 delimiter=';'
                 )
```

---

- Mensagem de erro, ao executar a célula:

**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'drive/My Drive/Path/Path/DM_ALUNO.csv'**

---

- Print com os arquivos na pasta do caminho.

[image: Pastas onde estão os cursos]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione /content/ antes de drive

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

base = pd.read_csv ('/content/drive/My Drive/Path/Path/DM_ALUNO.csv'')
```

Comment: continuou com o mesmo erro:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'content/drive/My Drive/Path/Path/DM_ALUNO.csv'
```

Comment: Seus arquivos realmente estao nestes diretorios (/Path/Path/), pelo print nao dar pra ver?

Comment: Voce esqueceu tambem a / no inicio

Comment: Estão sim, o SGL_ESTADOS eu consegui importar, os outros não.

Comment: Consegui, realmente era isso que estava faltando! Mas tinha uns erros (de digitação) que estava na minha cara e eu não estava vendo